# How many times will the innermost loop be iterated

Tags: combinatorics

How many times will the innermost loop be iterated when the algorithm segment is implemented and run? Assume $n$, $m$, $k$, and $j$ are positive integers.

```
for k :=1 to n
 for j :=k to n 
  for i := j to n 
   [Statements in the body of the inner loop, none containing branching statements that lead outside the loop]
  next i
 next j 
next k
```

I don't have a idea to start this one

Answer (score 1):

For each $i$, the statements are executed once.
As $i$ runs from $j$ to $n$ this produces
$$\sum_{i=j}^n1 = n+1-j $$
iterations.
For given $k$, $j$ runs from $k$ to $n$, hence the total number of iterations for that $k$ is $$\sum_{j=k}^n(n+1-j)=\frac{(n+2-k)(n+1-k)}{2}$$
(e.g., by using Gauss' summation trick).
Finally, as $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$, this produces
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n+2-k)(n+1-k)}{2}$$
iterations. I am too lazy to resolve that exactly, but it should be well-known that summing over a polynomial produces a polynomial of degree one higher (as was also the case in the first two steps: $1$ is constant, $n+1-j$ is linear in $j$, $\frac{(n+2-k)(n+1-k)}{2}$ is quadratic in $k$. Hence the final result will be a cubic in $n$.
By straightforward counting through the code for small $n$, we find that this cubic should map $1\mapsto 1$, $2\mapsto 4$, $3\mapsto 10$ - and by being courageous we note that $0\mapsto 0$ should still be covered by the formula.
As one easily verifies
$$ \frac16n^3+\frac 12n^2+\frac 13n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$
matches these four values and must be our desired cubic polynomial.

---

Inspired by *Logophobic*'s comment, here's another way to arrive at the result (or rather, to show it is correct once you know what it is - this can hardly be though of as a way to actually *find* the result):
Consider the following specific instance of code in the innermost loop:

```
for k := 1 to n do
   for j := k to n do
      for i := j to n do
         print k,j+1,i+2,EOL
      next i
   next j
next k
```

We make the following observations:

- each output line contains three integers $x,y,z$ with $1\le x<y<z\le n+2$
- no two output lines are equal
- for any integers $x,y,z$ with $1\le x<y<z\le n+2$ we find that it will be printed during the run of the program. Indeed, for $1\le x<y<z\le n+2$ let $k=x$, $j=y-1$, $i=z-2$ and note that the given inequalities imply $1\le k\le n$, $k\le j\le n$, $j\le i\le n$.
- In other words, for any three-element subset $A$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\}$ there exists exactly one line where the elements of are are printed in ascending order.

We conclude that the number of iterations equals the number of three-element subsets of an $(n+2)$-element set, that is 
$$n+2\choose 3 $$

Comment: Note that this is $\binom{n+2}{3}$

Comment: @Logophobic Indeed. Can you find a combinatorial counting argument for that?

Comment: I recognized the code for its similarity to code which I have used to enumerate combinations, so I knew immediately that the answer could be written in combinatorial form. No fancy math involved.